# Why does my gas oven not ignite properly?

Tags: gas, oven

I have a very old Magic Chef gas range. Every time I use the oven, I have to open the bottom drawer and fan air towards the pilot light at the back to get the flames going to heat up the oven. The pilot light does come on when I turn the oven temp. knob, it's that the long rows of flames do not light up unless I fan air into the bottom of the oven. What is the problem? Why do I have to fan it every time? And can this be fixed, or is the range just too old? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Just thinking the jets closest to the pilot are clogged and when you fan the gas gets close enough to the pilot to ignite.

Sounds like you need to have all the burner jets cleaned.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Burning gas and certain kinds of food combine to leave a residue that can plug the gas distributor in the broiler.
Try scrubbing with an old and dry toothbrush.